# Why is it wrong to use option types in a discriminated union?

Tags: types, f#, treenode, discriminated-union

I am trying to create a tree node data type using discriminated union.

However, the compiler is giving me a error saying “anonymous type variables are not permitted in this declaration”

What causes the error?

```
type TreeNode = | TreeNode of int * (Some (TreeNode)) * (Some(TreeNode))
```

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that `Some` is one of the constructors of the `'T option` type (and so you can use it to create option values when writing an expression).

In the type definition of a discriminated union, you need to use the type name - if you want to have left and right branches where each of them can be missing, then the type is `TreeNode option`:

```
type TreeNode = | TreeNode of int * (TreeNode option) * (TreeNode option)
```

This is quite basic question, so I'd recommend looking at the [F# wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Option_Types) for more information (or pretty much any F# introduction or book).